# How to detect VoiceOver status changes in Mac app

Tags: macos, voiceover

I have a Mac application.

I want to enable / disable some app functionality depending upon if VoiceOver has been enabled or not.

I know that I can detect if VoiceOver has been enabled / disabled using [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] isVoiceOverEnabled].

Apart from this, I want to register for a notification to detect the changes in VoiceOver status (enabled / disabled).

I found that, this can be achieved in iOS by registering to UIAccessibilityVoiceOverStatusDidChangeNotification notification.

But, I did not find similar notification for macOS.

Can anyone please tell me how can I achieve this in macOS.

Answer (score 2):

You can use KVO to observe changes to `NSWorkspace.shared.isVoiceOverEnabled`

I used closure based KVO in Swift and added an observation property to my class:

```swift
private var voiceOverObservation: NSKeyValueObservation?
```

and in init:

```swift
voiceOverObservation = NSWorkspace.shared.observe(\.isVoiceOverEnabled) { _, _ in
    print(NSWorkspace.shared.isVoiceOverEnabled)
}
```